# How to replace a directory with a symlink using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I would like to replace `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` with a symlink to my repo. I'm trying to do this using `file` module, but that doesn't work as the file module doesn't remove a directory with force option.

```
- name: setup nginx sites-available symlink
  file: path=/etc/nginx/sites-available src=/repo/etc/nginx/sites-available state=link force=yes
  notify: restart nginx
```

I could fall back to using shell.

```
- name: setup nginx sites-available symlink
  shell: test -d /etc/nginx/sites-available && rm -r /etc/nginx/sites-available && ln -sT /repo/etc/nginx/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-available
  notify: restart nginx
```

Is there any better way to achieve this instead of falling back to shell?

Comment: Now that I read your question properly: why do you want to replace the entire sites-enabled folder? Isn't it more customary to add links in sites-enabled poitning to sites-available (or somewhere else, like your project)?

Comment: Thats how it was done in the earlier setup and I was trying to redo the same with Ansible. One thing I could have done is symlink /repo/etc/nginx/sites-available/* to /etc/nginx/sites-available/. In that case I'll have to remember to run ansible-playbook if I add a new site, which I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When you take your action, it's actually things:

- delete a folder
- add a symlink in its place

This is probably also the cleanest way to represent in Ansible:

```
tasks:
  - name: remove the folder
    file: path=/etc/nginx/sites-available state=absent 

  - name: setup nginx sites-available symlink
    file: path=/etc/nginx/sites-available 
          src=/repo/etc/nginx/sites-available 
          state=link 
          force=yes
    notify: restart nginx
```

But, always removing and adding the symlink is not so nice, so adding a task to check the link target might be a nice addition:

```
  - name: check the current symlink
    stat: path=/etc/nginx/sites-available 
    register: sites_available
```

And a 'when' condition to the delete task:

```
  - name: remove the folder (only if it is a folder)
    file: path=/etc/nginx/sites-available state=absent
    when: sites_available.stat.isdir is defined and sites_available.stat.isdir
```

Comment: That makes it 3 steps - stat, remove and link. It feels too much work for such a simple thing.

Comment: What if I need to do same work for list of files provided via `with_items`? How we can register stat results as array and access it in `when` statement?

Comment: Original question was `Why "force" directive doesn't work as expected`, I believe

Comment: Rather than  `when: sites_available.stat.isdir is defined and sites_available.stat.isdir`  I use `when: sites_available.stat.isdir | default(false)`   its smaller and feels cleaner